# Automatic (unwanted) on update triggers in mysql?

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm running Percona's fork of mysql (5.6.15) on Ubuntu 13.04. After spending far too long trying to debug a problem with one of our ETL processes, I discovered mysql was modifying my create table syntax:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test ( test TIMESTAMP );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> show create table test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

I don't want this on update trigger, I've discovered I can get around this by making the column a 'TIMESTAMP NULL' instead, but I also don't want this field to be nullable.

Am I totally off base or should this not be happening? Has anyone encountered this before? Is this some setting I'm not aware of or could this be a bug (I know they changed some behaviour of timestamp fields in 5.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's just that the first timestamp column in a table (if not specified otherwise) gets these attributes. Would you add another timestamp column, it would not get those attributes. Read more about it in the [**manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html). If you really really have a problem with it, maybe a datetime instead of timestamp column would be an option?

Comment: my google fu has failed me, thank you sir. I've chosen to change the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable to stop this behavior: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp